# best practices to implement update user email

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am implementing a update email feature for an app. 
Here are my db tables

```
users: id, username, password, email, is_verified
email_verification: id, user_id, new_email, token
```

Process:

User requests for email update by filling a form containing the present and future emails.

App generates a token, persists it to `email_verification` with associated data. Then send emails to accounts. (Notification to present email, Verification to future one).

If users, verifies, App checks for token validation and other stuffs then replace email in `users`. Finally, logs the user session out on all devices to re-authenticate.

My question is: Can I get a more elegant solution? (I am using laravel, if it helps)

Comment: Check this out: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/58503/best-practices-for-a-change-of-email-user

Answer (score 0):

a good way to do this would be to send the email first to old email verify that the user want to change email and show which email is the new email  then when they click on the link in  email it will generate a token store the value and send another email to the new email address where there they will click the link to update email Address on check your app will see the token and and the old email verify that a match then update

> link for new email :  encode
>   link/method(token)/(old_email)/(new_email)  //your order

in your controller get each segment and decode them   use salt if needed

so if the encoded values are tampered it will not work

**EDIT:**
verify all 3 segments in your db if all 3 match do the update  and then remove the token or set the token field to some other random digit set so that  after the update they cant click the link again

Comment: I would have loved to used this method but I wont work for users that no longer have access to their emails